# Filtering list with discriminating union type to a single type

Tags: f#

Given a type

```
type C = Circle of int | Rectangle of int * int
```

and a collection

```
let l = [ Circle(1); Circle(2); Rectangle(1,2)]
```

I want to handle only circles

```
 let circles = l |> List.filter(fun x-> match x with 
                                        | Circle(l) -> true
                                        | _ -> false)
```

But my circles are still of type C, thus I cannot do

```
for x in circles do
  printf "circle %d" x.??
```

I have to do

```
for x in circles do
  match x with 
  | Circle(l) -> printf "circle %d" l
  | _ -> ())
```

seems wrong..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `List.choose` -- it's like `List.filter` and `List.map` rolled into one.

```
let circles =
    l |> List.choose(fun x ->
        match x with 
        | Circle l -> Some l
        | _ -> None)

for x in circles do
  printf "circle %d" x
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l|>Seq.iter (function |Circle l->printf "circle %d" l|_->())
```